# Help with ViewData asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages

In my master page I have a menu that uses jquery ui accordion.

What is the best way to specify which item should be active??  the only thing I can think of is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#accordion").accordion({
                collapsible: true,
                autoHeight: false,
                active:<%=ViewData["active"] %>
            });          
        })
```

But it seems a little repetitive having to set ViewData["active"] everytime a View is called throughout my whole app... what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered putting the accordian in a PartialView?  Then you place your code within the PartialView and away from the Master page.

Also you can have a base controller which can set the ViewData for you so now it's in one place.

**Edit**

It's the same as any other base class.  Your controller inherits from `Controller` so your base class will need to do the same;

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyAppControllers
{
    public class ControllerBase : Controller
    {
        protected override void Execute(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            ViewData["ApplicationName"] = CacheHelper.Get().Name;
            base.Execute(requestContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Now set your controller class to inherit from the ControllerBase class;

```
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
```

I've also implemented a CacheHelper but you can obviously use your own flavour of storing the current value.

Comment: *fly on the wall here, not trying to hijack question, NachoF ;)*

griegs: do you mind elaborating on the emplementation of the base controller? :) Sounds interesting.

Again, sorry don't mean to hijack question, I'm having the same pondering as you, NachoF.

Comment: @bomortensen The base controller is simply a class that inherits Controller. It allows you to place your own logic into the OnActionExecuting and OnActionExecuted (among other) methods to inject logic, log errors, redirect or wotnot.